# Apache just working with private IP

Tags: networking, server, apache2, port-forwarding

I've just set up a new server, which is at my home, with Ubuntu in order to host some databases and a little website; I've done that many times with VPS but never with a machine in my own network.

I've installed LAMP and some other software in order to do what I need, but I'm stucked with a little problem: I just can reach my apache default page when I type the private IP address of the server in the browser: if I try to access using the public address the browser asks me some credentials of the DSL gateway; I suppose I'm trying to access to the condiguration page of my router instead of the apache page.

I've googled and I guess I'll have to open some ports and maybe change the default port of apache (I've already opened port 80 and it still doesn't work). I know it's a very basic question but I never dealed with this when my host was a VPS :/

Thanks so much, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: EDIT: Re-read what was happening. This is because of a NAT issue. Try accessing the server from outside of your network and it will work. Some routers just don't handle hairpin NAT correctly, mine included. It's easiest to just modify the host files of internal machines to correctly access the server.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a small home network behind DSL router, log in to your router settings 192.168.x.y and set up port forwarding on your router, you should set up port forwarding for port 80 from your router to the IP of machine hosting your LAMP server, this will forward all http requests on port 80 made to your router's public IP to your LAMP server behind the router. This is not related to Ubuntu though.